# Meaning of "white rectangles are subtracted from the sum of pixels in the grey rectangles" in Viola-Jones

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, face-detection

I am trying to understand the mean of result of subtraction "The sum of the pixels which lie within the
white rectangles are subtracted from the sum of pixels in the grey rectangles" by Viola-Jones. how is the result of subtraction related to the face?Thanks

Journal is from Robust Real-Time Face Detection by Paul Viola and Micheal J. Jones

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the Processing language? If not, it should not contain the [processing] tag.

Comment: Viola jones algorithm is used for face detection in image. It is an image processing. Im sorry the tag divided into two. Should be image processing, not image and processing.

Comment: You can edit your post to include the correct tags. Hopefully that'll get you some answers. But the question is also pretty vague, so you might want to try including a link to an exact article and an exact section of that article that you're confused about. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are talking about the [Haar-like features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar-like_features) used in the original variant of the Viola-Jones algorithm. The Haar-like features are very simple "box filters". They approximate first and second order Gaussian derivative filters.

Let's say you have a 1x4 Haar filter that looks like this: [-1 -1 1 1]. Applying this filter is equivalent to subtracting the sum of the two pixels on the left from the sum of the two pixels on the right. If you do this at every location in your image, you will get an approximation of the first-order x-derivative of the image.

Applying filters of this form, i. e. consisting of rectangular regions filled with 1 or -1 can be done very efficiently using a technique called *integral image*. This is why Haar features were used for the Viola-Jones algorithm.